# UIView over UIScrollView prevent it from scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `UITableView`, Each cell has a view like below image, a `UIScrollView` in **background** and another view on the UIScrollView.

UIScrollView contains multiple images and user should be able to see them by swiping right or left on the table cell, But as second View (**red area**) covered UIScrollview, Scrolling not work when I swipe my finger in this area, But in the top of red area it's ok and works perfect.

[image]

I see in the other application that have this feature that scrolling is possible in all cell height even when they have other views that covered the background.

I should be grateful if you share your suggestions with me :)

Comment: are you added that upper view as a subView on the scrollView?

Comment: add some code or you are using storyboard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try disable userInteraction on the view in the red area, this will allow touches to pass though it. this can be done through the storyboard, or just go `view.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: but what if i want to continue tapping of button that is inside that view ?

Comment: @AhemadabbasVagh if you can place the button outside of the view that has interactive disabled but on top of that view, that would be the easiest solution, but otherwise might have to find out how to pass touches up the responder chain instead of the view just absorbing it like normal, not sure how to do that off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

Keep this line of code in ViewDidLoad method:

```
    [self.view setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

And if this doesn't work add it for your tableview

```
    [tableView setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

Or else at the end you can add the swipe gesture to the tableview cell and call the selector and do which intended to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Add Second view as a subview of firstView or ScrollView.

```
[scrollView addSubview:firstView];
[firstView addSubview:secondView];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the view was not a subview of the `UIScrollView`.  You can check this by setting a breakpoint somewhere in your `UIScrollView` or the parent view controller class and entering the following in your debugger window:

```
po myScrollView.subviews
```

Then check the output to make sure that your element is within the subviews.

Answer (score 0):

```
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

and handle the scrolling by code.

```
func scrollToPage(page: Int) {
    var frame = scrollView.frame
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
    scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.